# let a,b,c be nxn invertable matrices what is ($A^{-1}B^{T}(C^{-1})^{T})^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra

($A^{-1}B^{T}(C^{-1})^{T})^{-1}$

This was a multiple choice on my exam. Once I finished the exam, I was able to bring the exam paper home.  This was the only question I had difficulty with, and I'm still unsure how to solve it.

I answered $C^{T}(B^{-1})^{T}A$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly your answer is good by the 3 properties :

(1) $(A^-1)^T=(A^T)^{-1}$

(2) $(A^{-1})^{-1}=A$

(3) $(A*B)^{-1} = (B^{-1}*A^{-1})$

(4) $(A*B)^T= B^T*A^T$

So, the answer $C^T*(B^{−1})^T*A$ is good

Comment: 4 properties, pardon me